# Generate csv URL from dropdown values and pass it to create a highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I am trying to have two drop-down inputs where based on the selected value from the drop-down the file-name for the particular data file will be generated and the same would be used as data source for a Line chart using highcharts.

Check out the code for what I am trying:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    var obj_motorId = document.getElementById("Motor");
    var motorId = obj_motorId.value;

    var obj_parId = document.getElementById("Parameter");
    var parId = obj_parId.value;

    var url = motorId + "_" + parId + ".csv";

    $.get(url, function(csv) {
      var speedSeries = [
        []
      ];
      var lines = csv.trim().split('\n');
      $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        if ((lineNo !== 0) && (line != "")) {
          var x = new Date(items[0]),
            speed1 = parseFloat(items[1]);
          var year = x.getFullYear();
          var month = x.getMonth();
          var day = x.getDate();
          var hour = x.getHours();
          var min = x.getMinutes();
          var thisDate = Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, min);
          speedSeries[0].push([thisDate, speed1]);
        }
      });

      var options = {
        series: [],
        chart: {
          zoomType: 'x',
          renderTo: "chart1"
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Parameter: '
        },

        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          title: {
            text: 'Sept 2, 2015 to Sept 30, 2015'
          },
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            //                            text: parName;   
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        },
      };

      options.series.push({
        data: speedSeries[0],
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Value'
      });

      var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<form>
  <select id="Motor">
    <option value="5045_01">Motor 1</option>
    <option value="5045_02">Motor 2</option>
    <option value="5045_03">Motor 3</option>       
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="Parameter">
    <option value="01.10">Parameter 1</option>
    <option value="01.11">Parameter 2</option>
    <option value="01.12">Parameter 3</option>
  </select>

  <button id="button1">Submit</button>

  <div id="chart1" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
```

The csv file that I am trying to generate the URL using the dropdown has name: "*5045_03_01.11.csv*" which is a combination of Motor Id *5045_03* with name *Motor 3* and Parameter name *Parameter 2*. My csv file with the name *5045_03_01.11.csv* has data in this format.

```
9/30/2015 6:39:14 PM,980.015137
9/29/2015 6:38:16 PM,964.247925
9/28/2015 6:37:15 PM,965.460938
9/27/2015 6:36:26 PM,996.995483
9/26/2015 6:35:16 PM,972.737671
9/25/2015 6:34:14 PM,972.737671
9/24/2015 6:33:14 PM,966.673218
```

I am able to get the values for both from the dropdown which I checked using an alert for both the dropdowns. I don't know whether the URL that I am trying to generate from the values selected is correct or not and is also being passed to the chart function.

Kindly help me with the same.

Comment: Ok, how about the question? What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: @PawełFus, The chart does not load when I choose the parameters

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? Does you AJAX work? Do you get empty chart (with title) or just blank space?

Comment: @PawełFus No the console does not show any errors. And I get blank space in the chart div.

Comment: Does your AJAX work? Add simple `console.log(csv)` inside: `$.get(url, function(csv) { ... })`.

Comment: I tried to add `console.log(csv)` inside: `$.get(url, function(csv) { ... })`, but nothing turned up in the console. @PawełFus

Comment: Then path to your CSV files is wrong or you are trying to load local files.

Comment: @PawełFus I am trying to generate the filename using the parameters from the dropdown menu. 
So this means that the _url_ is not generated in the variable which I am passing to get the csv ?
`var url = motorId + "_" + parId + ".csv";

    $.get(url, function(csv) `

Comment: I am not talking about CSV names - those are most probably proper. I mean, that you try to load CSV file from a wrong path. Or you don't have webserver (just html file) and trying to load local files from a folder, which won't work because of access control (CORS).

Comment: @PawełFus, okay! Yes I am hosting the html on localhost and trying to load the csv file from a local folder. What can I do to load files from a local folder?

Comment: The best I suggest it to setup some websrever, so files will be available as `http://localhost/myfile.csv`. There is plenty of options, like nodejs, MAMP etc.

Comment: @PawełFus I am already hosting it localhost. Accessing the file using `http://localost/5045_03_01.11.csv` gets the csv and downloads.

Comment: Then path is wrong, try this: `$.get("/" + url, function (csv) { ... } );`.

Comment: @PawełFus
Ok, May be adding `"/"` was the issue with the URL. Thank you for letting me know.
Now after making the changes when I selecting the parameters and choose the _Submit_ button. In the console, I checked that the URL is correct, it also shows that it is reading values from the data file. But it fails to load the chart and navigates back to localhost

Comment: What navigates you? It reloads the page? If chart still doesn't show up it is strange - at least chart's title should show up  (in case when data is corrupted): `'Parameter:'`.